# calling a method which is in different file

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I have two js files which are as follows:

### file1.js

```
(function($){
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.user = {
            getAnchorUrl : function (el){
                return jQuery(el).attr('href');
            }
        }       
    });
})(jQuery);
```

### file2.js

```
(function($){
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.popup-video-link').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = jQuery.user.getAnchorUrl(this);
            jQuery.user.getVideoPopupTemplate(url);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I am loading `file1.js` first then `file2.js`.

Whenever I click the anchor tag which has class `.popup-video-link`, I am getting error

> TypeError: jQuery.user.getAnchorUrl is not a function

Any help where I am going wrong?

PS: I am wrapping the jquery code because in this project I am also using prototype.js and many other plugins.

Comment: Because the function `getAnchorUrl` is in a document ready function.  Remove it from the document ready, and it will be available and work in the other script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `jQuery(function(){` from `file1.js`. Try this:

```
(function($){
    jQuery.user = {
        getAnchorUrl : function (el){
            return jQuery(el).attr('href');
        }
    }       
})(jQuery);
```

When using `jQuery(callback)` the call back is loaded when the page is loaded (like `$(document).ready(callback)`, almost), `(callback)(jQuery)` creates an anonymous function which is then called with the first parameter as `jQuery`

Comment: Should I remove `jQuery(function(){` from all the files? (_the above code is just an example_)

Comment: Check the edit I just did. The `jQuery` method should be used when you want the function you are passing to be called once the page is loaded, rather then while it it loading to speed things up.

Comment: No problem :). Was going to answer it myself but yeah.